# How can I implement AdMob interactive video on Android app?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have read a few places that Google is going to bring interactive video advertisements to their AdMob platform for Android developers. However, on their site, I cannot find any information on how to implement it, how much they usually pay per impression/click (average, not actual earnings), and there is even such a service from them. No SDK, no resources, no webpage, and no code; it seems non-existent. However, I have found a lot of sites that state that Google is bringing thease to Android.

**What could be going on? Did they cancel it? How can I implement these if I want to? Do I use the normal SDK? Does anybody know any of the average/typical earnings with this per impression or click?**

**EDIT:** I found [this](http://mashable.com/2010/10/25/android-admob-video-ads/) article and it says that there is a new SDK, but they are only bringing it to certain apps?!?! Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean Admob interstitial ads. These are available now using the Admob SDK. Instead of using an instance of AdView you want to use an instance of com.google.ads.InterstitialAd but otherwise it is not too dissimilar.

You are paid on a CPC basis unless Admob has specifically tapped you on the shoulder for a pay per impression service (you need a fair amount of traffic for that). I find that eCPM for the interstitials is about 3 to 5 times that of banner ads.

Comment: Does this mean it supports video ads too?

Comment: Yes. Admob interstitials can also serve video.